# animate show/hide from css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery so please be gentle with me.  I'm trying to animate a show/hide of several divs based on if it has a certain class or not.

Basically, I'm creating a site for a photographer and have a portfolio section with a list of filters along the top, each div has a class of "portfolio-items" as well as additional classes for all the categories it's in, so family / wedding / kids / couples.  any image can have multiple classes on it.

What I want to do is click on the family link and it hides anything that doesn't have the family class on it.  If I then click on wedding it closes anything that's currently open that doesn't have the wedding class on it and opens anything thats currently closed that does have the wedding class on it.

I currently have it working with the code below but this simply closes everything and then opens the ones that have the class required.  Plus I don't know how to add an animate to it.

```
function portfolioItems(filter) {
 $(".portfolio-items").hide();
 $("."+filter).show(); }

function initEventHandlers () {
 $(".port-all").click(function () { 
    $(".portfolio-items").show();   
    return false;
 })
 $(".port-wedding").click(function () {
portfolioItems("wedding");
return false;
 })
 $(".port-family").click(function () {
portfolioItems("family");
return false;
 })
 $(".port-kids").click(function () {
portfolioItems("kids");
return false;
 })
 $(".port-couples").click(function () {
portfolioItems("couples");
return false;
 }) }
```

The HTML is...

```
    <div class="portfolio-container">
        <div class="portfolio-links">
            <a href="#"><img alt="All" class="port-all" src="images/port-all.png" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img alt="family" class="port-family" src="images/port-family.png" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img alt="wedding" class="port-wedding" src="images/port-wedding.png" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img alt="couples" class="port-couples" src="images/port-couples.png" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img alt="kids" class="port-kids" src="images/port-kids.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio">
            <div class="portfolio-items wedding couples family"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-items kids"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-items wedding kids family"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-items couples"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-items couples kids family"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-items wedding"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have a look at .hasClass() http://api.jquery.com/hasClass

Comment: I had a look at that, but I couldn't figure it out, this is what I tried with that...  

    function showHidePortItems() {
        if (filter === "all") {
         $(".portfolio-items").show();
        }
        else {
            if( $(".portfolio-items").hasClass(filter)) {
         $(this).show();
     };
     else {
         $(this).hide();
     };
        };
    }

Comment: Please provide sample HTML so we can tailor responses to what you already have.

Comment: I've added the HTML to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you may use not selectors([look here](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)!) to avoid hiding all your photos. Just assign two classes to your blocks with photos. Something like this

```
    <div class="portfolio-items wedding"></div>
    <div class="portfolio-items family"></div>
    <div class="portfolio-items kids"></div>
```

And then you can rewrite your `portfolioItems` function in this way

```
    function portfolioItems(filter) {
        $(".portfolio-items:not(."+filter+")").hide();
    }
```

Secondly you may create one generic function for hiding some category, but not duplicating the same code by several times.

Comment: So would I end up with code like this...

    function portfolioItems(filter) {
        $(".portfolio-items:not(."+filter+")").hide(500);
 $("."+filter).show(500);
    }

Comment: yes, also think about the way you setting click handler. You can store active photo category in links data attributes, set delegate click on portfolio-links block, then on click you can get the event source and read it's category class from data attribute. Than just pass it to **portfolioItems** function. Hope that helps)

Comment: This works and I can add a timing to get it to animate a bit nicer.  Is there anyway to add a better animation to this?

Comment: depends on what you need, you can play with **animate** to change different css properties(opacity, position, margins, colors e.t.c)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function portfolioItems(filter) {
   $(".portfolio-items.not("+filter+")").fadeOut();
   $("."+filter).fadeIn(); 
}
```

Comment: **fadeOut** and **fadeIn** are for add some effect

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach I've found useful for filtering via CSS. I like to use the data attribute on links to specify a filter. To start, set up a navigation with some links and a portfolio with some images or divs:

```
<!-- set up some navigation -->
<nav>
    <a href="#" class="filter">All Photos</a>
    <a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".family">Family Photos</a>
    <a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".art">Art Photos</a>
    <a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".wombats">Wombat Photos</a>
</nav>

<!-- set up a portfolio -->
<div class="portfolio">
    <div class="family item">Some family image or something</div>
    <div class="art item"> Some art image or something</div>
    <div class="wombats item">Some wombat image or something</div>
    <div class="wombats item">Some wombat image or something</div>
    <div class="art item"> Some art image or something</div>
</div>
```

Notice how each of the a tags has the class name you'd want to use as a filter as a data-filter attribute. You can specify multiple classes in here and it'll work just the same. For instance ".wombat.family" would let you use a DOUBLE filter in your portfolio.

Here's a script that will help you get set up to filter:

```
//on document ready
$(document).ready(function(){

  //when you click <a> tag in the <nav>
  $("nav a").click(function(e){

    //if the <a> has a data-filter attribute
    if($(this).attr("data-filter")){

         //show all the .items with the class in the data-filter attribute
         $(".portfolio .item"+$(this).attr("data-filter")).show(300);

         //hide all the .items that do not have that class
         $(".portfolio .item:not("+$(this).attr("data-filter")+")").hide(300);

    }else{

      //if there's no data-filter attribute, show all the images
      $(".portfolio .item").show(300);
    }
  });
});
```

For this one, I'm simply using a time in the show() and hide() functions, but fadeIn() fadeOut() might work for you as well.

To enable the "all" filter, I simply didn't write a data-filter attribute for that particular a tag and made sure JS knew what to do (check the if/else).

The important thing to remember is the link between the class used on the portfolio item and the data-filter attribute. Pretty simple to get started, though I'm sure it'll get a little more complicated before you get finished :)

Here's a jsfiddle to play around: http://jsfiddle.net/w4VWm/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what kind of transition you want, but this will do a fade in/out with very little jquery:

please note, you may be able to remove some of the stuff in the divs, but i didn't know what you needed for other things on the page

the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5uXP/

```
    <div class="portfolio-container">
        <div class="portfolio-links">
            <a href="#" data-type="all"><img alt="All" class="port-all" src="images/port-all.png" /></a>
            <a href="#" data-type="family"><img alt="family" class="port-family" src="images/port-family.png" /></a>
            <a href="#" data-type="wedding"><img alt="wedding" class="port-wedding" src="images/port-wedding.png" /></a>
            <a href="#" data-type="couples"><img alt="couples" class="port-couples" src="images/port-couples.png" /></a>
            <a href="#" data-type="kids"><img alt="kids" class="port-kids" src="images/port-kids.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio">
            <div class="portfolio-items wedding couples family"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-items kids"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-items wedding kids family"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-items couples"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-items couples kids family"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-items wedding"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
  var $container = $("div.portfolio-container"),
      $portfolio = $container.find("div.portfolio");

 $container
 .on("click", ".portfolio-links a", function(event){
   var $obj = $(this);
  event.preventDefault();
  $portfolio
   .fadeOut()
  .queue(function(next){
    $($(this)[0]).css("color", "red")
     .removeClass("family wedding couples kids")
     .addClass($($obj[0]).data("type"));
    next();
  })
   .fadeIn();
 });
 });

</script>

<style>
 .portfolio .portfolio-items{
  display: none;
 }
 .portfolio.all .portfolio-items,
 .portfolio.family .portfolio-items.family,
 .portfolio.wedding .portfolio-items.wedding,
 .portfolio.couples .portfolio-items.couples,
 .portfolio.kids .portfolio-items.kids{
  display: block;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide all, add the new classname to a filter string then show by the filter string

http://jsfiddle.net/uhCY5/3/

```
var filters = "";

function portfolioItems(filter) {
    filters += '.' + filter
    $(".portfolio-items").hide();
    $(filters).show();
    $("#filter").text(filters)
}

function initEventHandlers() {
    $(".port-all").click(function () {
        filters = "";
        $(".portfolio-items").show();
        return false;
    })
    // the rest is the same
}
```